# skip record if empty, blank, or has 'N/A'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium

I am trying to simply skip over a record that is found within my relevant excel file as: empty, blank, or 'N/A'. I want the script to continue or skip; not stop if a record is found empty, N/A.

I am trying the below, but the script is still stopping at a blank, or N/A found record in the excel file....

```
    for row in excel_data.itertuples():
        mrn = row.MRN

        if mrn in ("", " ", "N/A", None) or math.isnan(mrn):
            print(f"Invalid record: {row}")
            excel_data = excel_data.drop(excel_data.index[row.Index])
        else:
            num_valid_records += 1

    print(f"Processing #{num_valid_records} records")
```

**More context:**

I'm importing data from an excel file, to pandas, to a web page (web form).

- I noticed the excel file has a few cells with values as 'N/A'.
- In the pandas data frame a few values are also outputting as 'NaT'.
- Currently as is my script is stopping when excepting a Date record
  from a cell, but instead this cell contains a 'N/A'. This entry is
  not required, so I just want it to skip if N/A is found, instead of stopping.
- I want it to simply skip this problem cell (i.e. found blank, or
  within N/A') and continue with the other records.

Comment: I've added more details, the script doesn't continue to the next record with my efforts, it just stops.

Comment: does it go inside of `if` block?

Comment: Please add a snapshot of your data as `example data`. See more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Can you try exception handling here, if there is na value catch valueerror:

Comment: What is your expected output? Dont think your question is hard to solve. Its just hard to understand what your data looks like and what your goal is.

Comment: I'm importing data from an excel file, to pandas, to a web page (web form). I notice the data excel file has a few values as 'N/A' - and in the pandas data frame a few values are outputting as 'NaT' - currently as is my script is failing when excepting a Date record, but is finding a 'N/A' in that cell in the Excel file - I want it to simply skip this problem cell and continue going.

Answer (score 1):

Find a true positive and use that record as a test.  Alternatively, they may be evaluating to nan in your pandas dataframe, therefore a good ole .dropna() may do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks, Do I really want to DROP it, or just skip it?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and the code does not stop in `Blank` or `NaN` or  values. There should be something wrong in your data. Just print out the row that stops your code to see what's the value of that column is. Alternately, you can check for null values with python functions like: `is None` or `== None` or something like that.

Comment: In the pandas dataframe, a few of the records are outputting 'NaT'

Comment: `NaT` looks weird. Please check the actual values of data and user `UTF8` format. Maybe there are some issues with the encoding of your data